# Estimating conditional effect in generalized linear regression model (GLM)

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, conditional-expectation, statsmodels

I am trying to understand if it's possible to estimate conditional effect in a GLM using an approach similar to how we would in a linear model.

Specifically in a linear model, I can use a residual method to estimate the conditional effect ($\beta^\ast$) and standard error of variable $g$ in this linear model $E(y) = X \beta + g \beta^\ast$, where $X$ is a matrix of covariates and intercept. The method is described as follows:

1. Fit a covariate-only model $E(y) = X \beta$ and get estimates $\hat{\beta}$
2. Calculate the residuals $E(\tilde{y}) = y - X \hat{\beta}$.
3. Project out the covariates from g by $\tilde{g} = g - X (X^T X)^{-1}X^T g $. Or equivalently regressing out $X$ from $g$ in linear model.
4. Refit a model $E(\tilde{y}) = \tilde{g} \beta^\ast $, which should give the same slope and (very close) standard error estimate as the estimates from fitting the original full model.

I attempted to apply this approach to GLM model using offset but found this residual method gives different estimates compared to the full model result. For example, for logistic regression, I tried the following using `statsmodel` in python:

1. Fit $logit(\mu) = X \beta$, get estimates $\hat{\beta}$ and the weight in logistic regression at convergence, where the weight is $\text{weight}_i = \hat{\mu_i} (1-\hat{\mu_i})$.
2. Calculate the linear predictor $\eta = X \hat{\beta}$.
3. Project out the covariates from g by $\tilde{g} = g - X (X^T W X)^{-1}X^T Wg $, where $W$ is a diagonal matrix of individual weight.
4. Fit the logistic model $logit(y) = \tilde{g} \beta^\ast$ with the linear predictor $\eta$ as offset. However, I observed very different results from the correct estimates in the full model.

Given that we regress out the MLE estimates from $g$ and include its prediction to offset $y$, I would have thought that the effect-size estimate for $g$ would match its estimate under the joint model. What am I misunderstanding?

See the example result output below:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as npla
from numpy import random

# simulate under logistic model
n = 100
random.seed(1)
X1 = random.normal(size=n).reshape((n,1))  # covariate
g = random.normal(size=n).reshape((n, 1))  # variable of primary interest
intercept = 0.5
X = np.hstack([np.ones_like(X1), X1, g])
beta = np.array([intercept, 1.0, 2.0]).reshape([3,1])
eta = X @ beta
prob = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-eta))
y = random.binomial(n=1, p=prob)

# fit full model y ~ X1 + X2
mod_full = sm.GLM(y, X, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()

# covariate only model: y ~ X1
covar = X[:, 0:2]
mod_covar = sm.GLM(y, covar, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()

mod_null_eta = mod_covar.get_prediction(covar, which="linear").predicted
mod_null_mu = mod_covar.get_prediction(covar, which="mean").predicted

glm_weight = mod_null_mu * (1 - mod_null_mu)
w_half_X = np.diag(np.sqrt(glm_weight)) @ covar
w_X = np.diag(glm_weight) @ covar

# regress out covar from X2
projection_covar = covar @ npla.inv(w_half_X.T @ w_half_X) @ w_X.T  # nxn
X2_resid = g - projection_covar @ g

# fit model y ~ X2_resid with offset
mod_X2 = sm.GLM(y, X2_resid, family=sm.families.Binomial(), offset=mod_null_eta).fit()
```

The result from full model is:

```
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
const          0.0779      0.285      0.274      0.784      -0.480       0.636
x1             1.3113      0.417      3.146      0.002       0.494       2.128
g             2.5512      0.552      4.622      0.000       1.469       3.633
==============================================================================
```

The result under residual method is:

````
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [0.025      0.975]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
g             2.1360      0.433      4.934      0.000       1.288       2.984
==============================================================================

```
````